# Incomplete \iffalse with \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: errors, pgfmath

I want to generate a table with the `\foreach` command such that the entries of the table depend on the row and column. I wanted to test the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}   
\newcommand*\tas[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sat}{#1+#2}
\sat
}    
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
\foreach \j in {1,...,7}{
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\tas{\i}{\j}}
    \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

This gives the error "Incomplete \iffalse". I read that the reason for this error is the use of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` is not expandable, so it is not “evaluated” in an `\edef` (which is what `\xappto` does, in the variant `\xdef`).

You can first compute the sum, storing it into a macro, then append the expanded version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand*\tas[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sat}{#1+#2}%
}
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{%
\foreach \j in {1,...,7}{%
    \tas{\i}{\j}%
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\sat &}
  }%
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use expandable arithmetic: `expl3` provides it, with `xfp` and `\fpeval`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox,xfp}

\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{%
\foreach \j in {1,...,7}{%
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\fpeval{\i+\j}&}
  }%
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to show the capabilities (not all covered by `pgfmath` is available, though), if you change the `\xappto` call into

```
\xappto\mytablecontents{\fpeval{round(\i*sqrt(\j),2)}&}
```

the output would be

[image]

The same result with full `expl3` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 7 }
 { % outer cycle: #1
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 7 }
   { % inner cycle: ##1
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \fp_eval:n {round(#1*sqrt(##1),2)} & }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \\ }
 }
\tl_set_eq:NN \mytablecontents \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}    

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

Note that `\tl_put_right:Nx` is the analog of `\eappto` (`x` stands for e*x*panded) and `\tl_put_right:Nn` is the analog of `\appto`. No need for global definitions, as `\int_step_inline:nnnn` does not use grouping of cycles: the current index is directly available as `#1` (or `##1` in the inner loop).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using that `newcommand`, you can calculate the same result using the option `[evaluate = \j as \c using int(\i+\j)]` of the inner `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate = \j as \c using int(\i+\j)] in {0,...,7}{
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\c}
    \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

You can also use:

```
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\c{\i+\j}
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\c}
    \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your execution of

```
\xappto\mytablecontents{\tas{\i}{\j}}
```

assumes that `\tas{.}{.}` is expandable. However, since it contains an assignment (`\pgfmathsetmacro`), it is not. Therefore, you'll have to evaluate (expand) the expression first before inclusing it as part of your `app`endage to `\mytablecontents`. Since the expression is fairly straight-forward (the addition of two numbers), you can just use `\number\numexpr#1+#2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand*\tas[2]{%
  \number\numexpr#1+#2\relax
}

\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
  \foreach \j in {1,...,7}{
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\tas{\i}{\j}}
    \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|ccc|cc}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Expandable calculation is easily possible via the LaTeX2e interface for `\fp_eval` from LaTeX3 in the [`xfp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfp):

```
\usepackage{pgffor,xfp,etoolbox}

\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
  \foreach \j in {1,...,7}{
    \xappto\mytablecontents{\fpeval{\i+\j}}
    \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}
```