# How (if at all) can one use datatool's \DTLforeachkeyinrow in an siunitx table?

Tags: siunitx, datatool

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{data}
\DTLnewrow{data}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{x}{1}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{y}{2}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{z}{3}
\DTLnewrow{data}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{x}{4}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{y}{5}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{z}{6}

%\robustify\DTLforeachkeyinrow

\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}{SSS}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    %\robustify\DTLforeachkeyinrow
    {x} & {y} & {z} \\
    \DTLforeach{data}{}{%
        %\robustify\DTLforeachkeyinrow%
        \DTLforeachkeyinrow{\dataValue}{%
            \ifnumgreater{\dtlcol}{1}{&}{}%
            \dataValue%
        }\\
    }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/NixOS.org) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.2)  22 FEB 2021 12:13
[...]
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
```

With columns `lll`, this works fine, producing a table of all the data from `datatool`. If I change the column specification `lll` to `SSS`, many mysterious errors appear. The `siunitx` manual, §7.2, suggests `\robustify`ing the `datatool` command, but trying to sprinkle `\robustify\DTLforeachkeyinrow` in various different places in the code doesn't seem to help.

**Can I use `\DTLforeachkeyinrow` together with `siunitx`?** Suppose there are enough columns in the database that listing them all in the second argument of `\DTLforeach` would be annoying.

---

I thought I might be able to make this work by expanding the table body first, like—

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_last_unbraced:Ne \begin {
    \exp_not:n {
        {tabular}{SSS}
            {x} & {y} & {z} \\
    }
    \DTLforeach{data}{}{
        \DTLforeachkeyinrow{\dataValue}{
            \int_compare:nNnT {\dtlcol} > {1} {\exp_not:N &}
            \dataValue
        }
        \exp_not:N \\
    }
    \exp_not:N \end{tabular}
}
```

—but this gives another error I don't understand,

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 34.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the "Incomplete \iffalse" error message I got with the `expl3` attempt, I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364626/incomplete-iffalse-with-pgfmathsetmacro/364643#364643) by egreg that reminded me to try building up the body of the table outside it, in a context that isn't so fiddly. This worked:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{data}
\DTLnewrow{data}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{x}{1.1}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{y}{2.2}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{z}{3.3}
\DTLnewrow{data}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{x}{4.4}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{y}{5.5}
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{z}{6.6}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% I know it's customary to use the question-asker's username as the L3 macro
% name prefix, but `user570286' isn't valid in a TeX macro name....
\tl_new:N \l__SIDataTab_body_tl

\DTLforeach {data} {} {
    \DTLforeachkeyinrow \g__SIDataTab_val_tl {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l__SIDataTab_body_tl {
            \int_compare:nNnT {\dtlcol} > {1} {&}
            \exp_not:V \g__SIDataTab_val_tl
        }
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__SIDataTab_body_tl {\\}
}

\begin{tabular}{SSS}
    {x} & {y} & {z} \\
    \l__SIDataTab_body_tl
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```